# Problem finding the right place to put Services/ViewModel in a MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, s#arp-architecture

I have a S#arp MVC application with following projects/layers :

- Core (Model)
- Data
- Web (View)
- Controllers
- Services

One example to show the problem:
I have a model **Ticket** :

```
public class Ticket : Entity
{
     public virtual string Summary { get; set; }
     public virtual string Description { get; set; }       
     public virtual DateTime CreateOn { get; set; }        
     public virtual DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
     public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
     public virtual User AssignedTo { get; set; }
     public virtual Priority Priority { get; set; }        
     public virtual Status Status { get; set; }        
}
```

Its located in Core project...

To my View Create(Ticket) I need a **CreateTicketViewModel** :

```
public class CreateTicketVM
{
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
     public string Summary { get; set; }

     [Display(Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
     public string Description { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
     public int AssignedToId { get; set; }     

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
     public int PriorityId { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
     public virtual int StatusId { get; set; }      

     public IList<User> Users { get; set; }       
     public IList<Priority> Priorities { get; set; }
     public IList<Status> Status { get; set; }        
}
```

Its located in Controller project...

So far so good... But in my TicketController I need fill all CreateTicketVM lists (dropdownlists in View).

So I created a **TicketService** :

```
public class TicketService : ITicketService
{       
     readonly IRepository<User> userRepository;
     readonly IRepository<Priority> priorityRepository;
     readonly IRepository<Status> statusRepository;
     ...     

     public CreateTicketVM CreateNewCreateTicketVM()
     {
         var _ticket = new CreateTicketVM();
         _ticket.Priorities = priorityRepository.GetAll();
         _ticket.Status = statusRepository.GetAll();
         _ticket.Users = userRepository.GetAll();
          _ticket.Categories = categoryRepository.GetAll();
          return _ticket;
     }
}
```

Its located in Service project...

The problem is with the Interface ITicketService :

```
public interface ITicketService
{
    CreateTicketVM CreateNewCreateTicketVM();
}
```

It´s located in Core project... But Core Project cannot include Controller project (CreateTicketVM) ...

So, how can I handle that?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of putting your CreateNewCreateTicketVM method on your service I would create an enhanced query object in your Controllers project for this. The services layer is then only concerned with behaviour.

See my blog post:

http://www.yellowfeather.co.uk/2011/03/enhanced-query-objects-with-sharp-architecture/

and Ayende's review:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/04/01/code-review-sharparchitecture.multitenant.aspx

Comment: Thanks ChrisR and Alec... To create a enhanced query object Am I supossed to change the S#arp code like your blog post Chris?

Comment: No, the changes to the S#arp code are only for multi-tenant support, but are in the 1.9.6 release anyway. You just need to add the NHibernateQuery base class to your Data project, create your query interfaces and classes, and make sure they are registered in the container (see SharpArchitecture-MultiTenant.Web/CastleWindsor/ComponentRegistrar.cs)

Answer (score 2):

Chris nailed that one. Use the query object to project straight into your view model.

Answer (score 1):

When you return a ViewModel (or a DTO, name doesn't matter), filled with ILists only meant to be displayed in a view, you're already tightly coupled to your view, from a "semantic" point of view.

Aren't you over engineering something here, that can't be solved with less projects, like :

- Core : Infrastructure blocks that can be shared with other apps
- MyApp : Specific code for your application, ordered with namespaces

  - MyApp.Data
  - MyApp.Services (service interfaces)
  - MyApp.Services.Implementations (if you really want to separate)
- MyApp.Web

  - MyApp.Web.Models
  - MyApp.Web.Controllers

MyApp.Web can be an MVC project, or if you want, 2 projects, one c# library with controllers, and 1 MVC project with only views.

In this case, I think it it too much to have a service layer build a ViewModel. This should be done in your controller, or better, by a tool like AutoMapper.

Service layer should have some business responsibilities : "does this user can assign ticket to this one at this precise time ?" for example.

Also, Ayende has a nice blog post about this : http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/03/16/architecting-in-the-pit-of-doom-the-evils-of-the.aspx

Don't forget : [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: My Service project has a Controller reference to access the CreateTicketVM object... So if ITicketService was located in the Service Project I´ll need to add Service reference on Controller, causing Circular dependency...

Comment: Updated answer. Still, if TicketService can reference CreateTicketVM without issue, then if ITicketService is located in the same project than TicketService, no problem will arise.

Comment: Thanks for help but if I put Interface in the same project I will get circular dependency :  Service Layer will need Controller to access ViewModel/DTO and Controller will need Service Layer to access Interface...

Comment: ViewModel belongs to controller/presentation layer. IMHO, If you use it in your service layer, something is wrong.

Comment: Yes, Of course something is wrong, thats why I´m here asking help :) ... I posted all relevant code, and I´m looking for a alternative solution...